# How to display an image from a SQL query that gives a file path in SSRS Report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a report, which I would like to display an image in my database from a query with a parameter. For example:

```
SELECT pictureATTACHMENT
FROM   myDatabase.dbo.ATTACHMENT
WHERE  DESCRIPTION LIKE @thisCampaign + '%'
```

My query returns a file path to the image:
For example:

```
\\DASERVER\FOLDER\FOLDER\Data\Attachment\filename.png
```

How do I need to format the expression for the report to display the image?

I have tried doing: `=file:\\DASERVER\FOLDER\FOLDER\Data\Attachment\filename.png`

But no luck.

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the image in the database as `Image` data type not as `varchar` and more over  SSRS should have permission to access the image .

Try this without `=` and in the image property dialogue box select the image source as `External` :-

```
 file:///<Location>\Image1.png
```

With the field from the dataset this can be done using the below expression again selecting the source as `External`

```
 ="file:///"+ Fields!pictureATTACHMENT.Value
```

If you are storing it as `blob` data then instead of `external` chose the property `Database` from the dropdown menu. Select the `pictureATTACHMENT` field from your dataset and `MiME` type as `png`

Comment: Thanks Praveen - I did as you suggested and it removed the error, but now gives me a warning: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\DASERVER\FOLDER\FOLDER\Data\Attachment\filename.png'. But the file path shouldn't contain C:\, is this some default setting?

Comment: I'm able to access the images located in `C:` .You should make sure that SSRS has access to the image . Try to give permission for the folder or image to `everyone` ,if its not that confidential.

Comment: Hi Praveen, this might be a stupid question - but from the file path it seems that the image is located on the database server, which SSRS should have access to - why is it trying to access my C: drive? Many thanks!