# How to display the image in SSRS using the imagepath from database. The image path is given as images/image1.png in database

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services

I am working in SSRS reports in that I need to display the logo for the report. I am having the image path in database like `images/image1.png.i` have used the external and database as the image source. But still no image is found in the logo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an image from a SQL query that gives a file path in SSRS Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454561/how-to-display-an-image-from-a-sql-query-that-gives-a-file-path-in-ssrs-report)

Comment: I followed the steps as mentioned but still it doesn't work for me.

Comment: In that case you need to show us exactly what you are doing... you haven't provided enough information to have any idea what is wrong.

Comment: That said the most likely issue is that the image path isn't accessible from your SSRS server.

Answer (score 1):

Image path prefix with `'File:FilePath'`  For Example

```
'File:D:\logo.jpg'
```

Comment: There are a few answers elsewhere on StackOverflow and the rest of the internets, that do not have this part in. Thanx for that, it solved my problem.